# Create cognito admin user on server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using aws cognito for authenticating and on backend side I need something like admin account to connect with cognito and check user attributes. I found that code below should works, but I got `user is not authorized to perform not authorized to perform on ...`
How can I create user with such privileges ?

`

```
let cisp = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()

var params = {
  AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
  ClientId: appConfig.ClientId,
  UserPoolId: appConfig.UserPoolId,
  AuthParameters: {
    USERNAME: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    PASSWORD: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
  }
}

cisp.adminInitiateAuth(params, (err, data) => {
  ...
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AWS cognito SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html) and call the following method to get information about the identity.

> describeIdentity(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request

If your code runs in AWS EC2, ECS or Lambda, you can attach a IAM role that has access to Cognito so that you code can access the Cognito API through SDK.

Else you need to create a IAM user with Cognito permissions and use AccessKey and Secret to authenticate the SDK API calls impersonating the user.